# How to set Administrators and permissions in Business Data Connectivity Service using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

While we are creating Managed Metadata service using powershell, New-SPMetadataServiceApplication have property -AdministratorAccount and -FullAccessAccount to set Administrator and permissions.

but in New-SPBusinessDataCatalogServiceApplication i have not found properties like that.

How can i add users in administrators and permissions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.
Here is an answer.

```
$principal = New-SPClaimsPrincipal "Domain\SP_Farm" -IdentityType WindowsSamAccountName

$spapp = Get-SPServiceApplication -Name "Search Service Application"

$security = Get-SPServiceApplicationSecurity $spapp -Admin

Grant-SPObjectSecurity $security $principal "Full Control"

Set-SPServiceApplicationSecurity $spapp $security -Admin
```

The above given code is worked if you want to add user in administrators.
If you want to add user in permissions remove -Admin.